# After Inserting a data to the Database Table the Navigation properties are nul

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-6, navigation-properties

When I am inserting data into the table using Entity Framework and while retrieving the data the Navigation property is null.

Eg. I have a table called Inventory and it has a Navigation properties called Type and Status.

without disposing the DbContext I am retrieving the data by passing the id.

at this point, the status and type models are null thought it has data.

Inventory: Inv_id Inv_nme type_id status_id

when i say : inventory.type.type_name

I am getting an error saying: null instance of an object.

To avoid the issue temporarily Eager Loading method using Include to call the submodels:

By using lazy load how can I get the navigation properties data like  :

inventory.type.type_name

inventory.status.status_name

Comment: Have a look at [`.Include("status")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: currently, I am using include only, but my question is is that ok if I use eager loading. Because I am using DB first and Lazy load is enabled. will it affect the performance?. As far as i know, if am using Include I have to remove virtual from the model yah?

Comment: Make sure the `status` and `type` properties in the `inventory` entity are marked as `virtual` in order for lazy loading to work. Also, the relationship must be configured. Can you show the entity model classes?

Comment: public partial class inventory{public inventory(){this.itemInv = new HashSet<itemInv>();}    
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> typId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> qty { get; set; }       
        public Nullable<int> statusId { get; set; }      
        public virtual status status { get; set; }
        public virtual type type { get; set; }       
        public virtual ICollection<itemInv> itemInv { get; set; }
    }